# ffmpeg rtp streaming появляется ошибка RTP: dropping old packet received too late

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtp

Привет всем!
Запускаю передачу видео средствами ffmpeg так:
`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 20 -tune zerolatency -s 800x600 -r 25 -b:v 0.9M -sdp_file video.sdp -f rtp rtp://192.168.10.24:5010`
Воспроизвожу так:
`ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp video.sdp`
Все работает просто замечательно. Затем прерываю передачу без остановки плеера и через пару секунд возобновляю. ffplay сразу не начинает воспроизводить а сыпятся ошибки:
`....
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 14 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 33 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 41 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 49 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 33 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 27 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 14 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 48 times
[sdp @ 0x6ebf80] RTP: dropping old packet received too lateB f=1/1
    Last message repeated 34 times
......`
 
Через какое то время воспроизведение восстанавливается.
Есть ли способ устранить или свести к минимуму появление ошибок такого характера при приостановке входящего потока, может опции или еще что? 
Читал мануал ffmpeg ничего путного по этому поводу не нарыл....((((

Comment: Неужели ни у кого нет идей по этому поводу?

Comment: Необходимо чтобы при возобновлении "вещания" плеер начинал воспроизведение сразу....а не через длительное время....без перезапуска плеера....очень нужна помощь....